# How to set i2c as module in beaglebone black

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c, beagleboneblack

Hello I am new in Linux kernel and I want to load i2c as a module in beaglebone black so how I can do this I search something regarding this (https://www.ddcutil.com/kernel_module/) but I don't understand how I do this  help me

Comment: "but I don't understand" - What **exactly** you don't understand from the link you provide? Have you tried the first command for check the type of i2c driver (module or built-in)? Have you tried to modify `/etc/modules-load.d` for mark the module as loadable on boot?

Comment: yes after grep i2c-dev.ko  /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.builtin command run they show me kernel/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.ko and after that I fire modprobe i2c-dev command to load module it does not show any error but after that, I can't see i2c-dev module in lsmod

Comment: Please, incorporate that comment into the question post. On Stack Overflow we expect the **question post** to contain all important information about the problem.